# Pgadmin server not contacted

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10, pgadmin-4

I just installed PostgreSQL 13 on my windows 10 pc and when I opened pgadmin 4 I got this error

[image: image of error]

please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try clearing out the C:\Users%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\pgAdmin folder and after that run de pgAdmin as Administrator